# mshtml.IHTMLElement getAttribute erratic behaviour

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, internet-explorer, microsoft.mshtml

In an application, I am using `mshtml.IHTMLElement.getAttribute(mimetype)` to extract the mimetype within a `mshtml.HTMLDocument`.

Example:

www.mywebsite.com/index.html. This webpage has 1 mimetype, and it is an Excel workbook.

```
Dim oHTML_Element As mshtml.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDoc As mshtml.HTMLDocument

HTMLDoc = CType(oBrowser.Document, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
'//mimtype = "Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
   If oHTML_Element.getAttribute("mimetype") is Nothing then
        MsgBox ("NONE FOUND")

   Else
       MsgBox( oHTML_Element.getAttribute("mimetype").ToString())

   End If
End For
```

The problem: 
   I am running this application sitting in location-1 (Asia Pacific), when I access that webpage, I get a pop-up `MsgBox` displaying `MIMETYPE`
   My colleague is running this application sitting in location-2 (Asia), when he accesses that webpage, he gets a pop-up `MsgBox`  displaying `NONE FOUND`.
   Webpage access is not the problem and we are accessing the webpage around the same time and its a static page , in other words it does not serve `MIMETYPE` based on geo-locations. He can access the Excel workbook by manually going into browser and clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I think I finally figured it out!

The culprit here is the `mimeType`. On my machine, I have MS Office 2010 installed whereas on my friend's machine he has Office 365.

Inside my C# code, I was searching for `mimeType = "Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet"` within `mshtml.HTMLDocument` and it worked fine. Now, searching for the same `mimeType` on the webpage rendered on my friend's machine yielded `None`. The problem was that `XLS` gets a `mimeType = "Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet"` when a machine has Office 365 and `mimeType = "Microsoft Office Excel 97-2003 Worksheet"` for older versions of Office.